# PHP - MySQL how to delete an image when a user submits a new image problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete the current image that is already set on the server when a user submits a new image to the server, but I don't know how to do add this to my current code can some one please help me?

Here is my PHP & MySQL code.

```
if(isset($_FILES["thumb"]["name"])) { 

  if (file_exists("/images/" . $_FILES["thumb"]["name"])) {

    $thumb != $_FILES["thumb"]["name"];

  } else if($_FILES["thumb"]["name"] == TRUE) {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["thumb"]["tmp_name"],
      "/images/" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlentities(strip_tags(basename($_FILES["thumb"]["name"])))));
    $thumb = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlentities(strip_tags(basename($_FILES["thumb"]["name"]))));

  } 

  if($thumb == TRUE) {
    //create thumb code here...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code

```
$filename=$_FILES['thumb']['name'];  
$oldimage='23.png'

if ((file_exists("thumb/".$oldimage))  && ($oldimage!=$filename)) {
    unset($oldimage);
  }
```

replace your if condition with above code inside if(isset(...){ 'here'

}

Comment: i updated my answer, and use single quote inside `$_FILE['']['']`

Comment: why u using `$thumb!=$_FILE['thumb']['name']` ? i think you shoud use `==` instead of `!=`

Comment: This code didn't work for me but thanks for your time and help.

Comment: It just wont delete the image its replacing.

Comment: replacing means it's deleting...
what u want more? and what is  in `$thumb` ?
OOPS! i m sorry u have to unset `$thumb` not `$filename`

Comment: I want the image to delete the other image with a different name its replacing for example `thumbs/23.jpg` should be replaced by `thumbs/24.png`